# My CSS button is doing a graphic issue with scale() when hover

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my CSS button that seems like a graphic issue. When I hover and put the cursor out seems like the border of the button bug and make a ghost border around the button. In chrome its more visible, but in Opera its like another kind of bug happens.

I noticed that when I take out the `transition: 0.3s` the issue is fixed on chrome, but I still need that the button scale in a smooth way.

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/573pxfgo/1/

```css
:root{
    --cor1:#206197;
    --cor2: #35ab4a;
}
div{
  padding:100px;
}

.btn2{
    color:white;
    padding:15px 40px;
    border:2px solid white;
    background-color: var(--cor1);
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.btn2:hover{
    background-color: var(--cor2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn2"> Solicitar Orçamento</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the error!

Comment: @aahad this is css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am not sure why the bug is happening, but a solution to fix it is to set the outline to 1px and make it transparent. You can also play around with the shadow of your button to make the rendering bug disappear. You can see my change at line ~ 14. Hope this works !

```css
:root{
    --cor1:#206197;
    --cor2: #35ab4a;
}
div{
  padding:100px;
}

.btn2{
    color:white;
    padding:15px 40px;
    border:2px solid white;
    background-color: var(--cor1);
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.btn2:hover{
    background-color: var(--cor2);
    transform : scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn2"> Solicitar Orçamento</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `background-clip:padding-box` to your `.btn2` class so that the background clips within the padding container of your element. Currently the color you are seeing as the very thin boundary of the border is the same color of your background and that is because by default, `background-clip:border-box` is applied.

You can read more about this from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

```css
:root{
    --cor1:#206197;
    --cor2: #35ab4a;
}
div{
  padding:100px;
}

.btn2{
    color:white;
    padding:15px 40px;
    border:2px solid white;
    background-color: var(--cor1);
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-clip:padding-box;
}

.btn2:hover{
    background-color: var(--cor2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn2"> Solicitar Orçamento</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still see an outline in the accepted answer, so here's another approach. This looks like a graphics bug created by the scaling. If you play around with different scaling values (try `transform : scale(2);`) you'll see the amount of the ghost border varies.

You can fix this by removing the white border: `border:none;`

If you need the border, try setting it in the outline instead: `outline: 2px solid white;`

```css
:root{
    --cor1:#206197;
    --cor2: #35ab4a;
}
div{
  padding:100px;
}

.btn2{
    color:white;
    padding:15px 40px;
    border:none;
    background-color: var(--cor1);
    outline: 2px solid white;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.btn2:hover{
    background-color: var(--cor2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn2"> Solicitar Orçamento</button>
</div>
```